# Insert text values from php array into javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, optimization

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec) ) {
$data_back[] = $row['Agencyname'];
}
$text_values = implode(", ", $data_back);

 var hprogress = new RGraph.HProgress('cvs', 0,maxlen,[<?php echo $collection?>])
        .Set('key', ['<?php echo $text_values?>'])
```

Above php array echos labels/names on top of a horizontal graph.

I tried array method to get text values(which represents names above that graph) though I can see their names but their are not formatted correctly.

So I'm unable to convey which label represents their respective value within the graph.
Thanks in advance mates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use json_encode to properly encode php array. instead of:

```
['<?php echo $text_values?>']
```

use

```
<?php echo json_encode($data_back); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks ziollek i have met my requirement now.